# Compilation of a file as if its contents were in specified package

Tags: compilation, lisp, package, common-lisp, prototyping

I've written a sort of DSL on top of Common Lisp. The domain is quite strange and my language looks quite different from Common Lisp itself. I've put all interface into a package `foo`:

```
(defpackage :foo
  (:use     :common-lisp
            :internal-machinery)
  (:shadow  :in-package
            :*packages*))
```

Switching between packages is beyond of the language concept, so I've disabled this ability by shadowing symbols `in-package` and `*package*`. Now user (programmer) of my language will be unable to switch packages. Fine.

Obviously, I want to use Common Lisp compiler to compile programs written in this language. Function `compile-file` looks OK for me. But there are difficulties.

I want to compile a file as if its contents were inside of my `foo` package. Putting `(in-package :foo)` on top of every program in my prototypical language is an undesirable option.

To make things even worse, I have to compile a file inside of a function:

```
(in-package :internal-machinery)

(defun compile-stuff (filename)
  (in-package :foo)                 ; it will have no effect, because
                                    ; this macro must be top level form

  (compile-file filename)           ; other options are omitted

  (in-package :internal-machinery)) ; no way, even if it were top level
                                    ; form, in-package is shadowed
```

I have no idea if it's possible or not, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the user can always call `(cl:in-package "FOO")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
(defun compile-stuff (filename)
  (let ((*package* (find-package '#:foo)))
    (compile-file filename)))
```

PS. As Rainer mentioned in a comment, if you offer REPL to the user, you are *not* safe from the user changing the package with `(cl:in-package "CL-USER")`.

Comment: Works! I knew it was that simple or impossible. Thanks a lot! :-)